# LXML raises XMLSyntaxError when validates boolean type attribnute against an XML Schema

Tags: python, xml, xsd, lxml

Here is a simple schema, which declares an element `root` with a single boolean attribute, named `foo`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="foo" type="xs:boolean" default="false"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Here is the XML, that complies to the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<root
    foo="true"
/>
```

And here is the Python code, that parses the XML and validates it against the schema:

```
import lxml
import lxml.etree


schema_parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser(load_dtd=True)
schema_doc = lxml.etree.parse(open('test.xsd'), parser=schema_parser)
schema = lxml.etree.XMLSchema(schema_doc)
parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser(
    load_dtd=True,
    dtd_validation=False,
    attribute_defaults=True,
    schema=schema
)
settings = lxml.etree.parse(open('test.xml'), parser=parser)
```

It produces a strange exception: `XMLSyntaxError: Element 'root', attribute 'foo': '' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:boolean'.`.

Notice `'foo': ''` part - it means, that LXML think, that the attribute is empty, for some reason.

Why it happens?

p.s.
I use LXML 3.6.4

Comment: It works for me. I can only reproduce the error if I change the attribute to `foo=''`.

Comment: @mzjn, can you give output of this command: `python -c "import sys; from lxml import etree; print('%-20s: %s' % ('Python', sys.version_info)); print('%-20s: %s' % ('lxml.etree', etree.LXML_VERSION)); print('%-20s: %s' % ('libxml used', etree.LIBXML_VERSION)); print('%-20s: %s' % ('libxml compiled', etree.LIBXML_COMPILED_VERSION)); print('%-20s: %s' % ('libxslt used', etree.LIBXSLT_VERSION)); print('%-20s: %s' % ('libxslt compiled', etree.LIBXSLT_COMPILED_VERSION))"`? What version of LXML and what OS do you use?

Comment: I use Python 2.7.12 and lxml 3.6.4 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I *can* reproduce, with the following setup (on Windows 10, Cygwin):

```
Python              : sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=13, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
lxml.etree          : (3, 7, 3, 0)
libxml used         : (2, 9, 4)
libxml compiled     : (2, 9, 4)
libxslt used        : (1, 1, 29)
libxslt compiled    : (1, 1, 29)
```

Furthermore, if I do

```
>>> x=etree.parse("testa.xml")
>>> x.getroot().attrib['foo']
```

the result is 'true'

This has been fixed in the libxml2 git repo (https://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2/commit/?id=3169602058bd2d04913909e869c61d1540bc7fb4), if you download source from there, compile and install, then remake lxml from source, this fixes things.

Alternatively, revert to libxml2-2.9.3 and remake lxml (but that may have other problems...)